# NLog writes the archived content to the current log file

Tags: logging, nlog

I am using NLog for logging in xamarin forms application, config settings are archive everyday, archive numbering set to rolling, concurrent writes set to true, max archiving 15. The problem is nlog is writing the archived content to the current log file with actual log appended to it.

Comment: Maybe check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting ? What was included in the app-update? (New version of NLog? Or something else updated?)

Comment: some of the old packages were updated

Comment: Sounds like you are on top of things, and have all the information needed to solve the issue. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the link i enabled the LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true and the app threw System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied. but the storage permissions are granted.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3426

Comment: If using NLog 4.5 (or newer) then just use `fileName="${shortdate}.log"` with `maxArchiveFiles=7` (And remove all other file-target archive parameters). Then NLog will stop doing File.Move. But only File.Delete

Comment: Still am getting the same unauthorized exception every alternate launch of the app after changing the device date. But the logging is happening correctly when the exception is not thrown.